# How to implement PUT function for PHP web services

Tags: php, sql, rest

I  want to use PUT function to add a user,( SIGN UP) 
I have done this using POST,
But I don't understand how will I do this using PUT,
I am just adding user name and a password.

Comment: [this is documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) for put... but it looks like it is mostly for files.

Answer (score 0):

Put requests you need to handle yourself. Data comes to php like this

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
```

The data still needs to be processed though as all variables are in one string. Depending on the method used to encode would change how you decode. It could be JSON for example

This can only be used once so keep the putdata variable

To know its been PUT look at

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Comment: `$this->load->database();
 $username = file_put_contents('username'];
 $password = file_put_contents['password'];
 $info = array('userid'=> null, 'username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password);
 $this ->db->insert('users', $info);
 $data->username = $username;
 $data->password= $password;
 $this->response($data,200);
     
        }` This is the code so far, but file_put_content shows an error, I just want PUT method to be used to add a user thru apigee.com/console